# PictureBoxSizeMode is error?

Tags: c#, winforms

Getting error when its casting in Listview:

```
    private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int a = 1;
        string theimage = textBox1.Text + @"\allimages\";
        foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.SelectedItems)
        {   
            // 39 zero's + "1"
            string initValue = new String('0', 3) + "0";
            // convert to int and add 1
            int newValue = Int32.Parse(initValue) + a;
            // convert back to string with leading zero's
            string newValueString = newValue.ToString().PadLeft(4, '0');

            string imageslist =  "product" + newValueString + "img";
            string[] images = Directory.GetFiles(theimage, imageslist + "*.jpg");

            // Cast the Picturebox
            PictureBox myPicBox = new PictureBox();
            myPicBox.Location = new Point(7, 240);
            myPicBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(140, 140);
            myPicBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
            myPicBox.Margin = new Padding(3,3,3,3);
            myPicBox.Visible = true;
            myPicBox.Image = new Bitmap(images[1]);
            Controls.Add(myPicBox);
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            //List<PictureBox> pictureBoxList = new List<PictureBox>();
        }

    }
```

Its my error:

> Error  1   'test.Form1.PictureBoxSizeMode()' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context    C:\Users\radiaku\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\test\test\Form1.cs   428 37  test

the code above working fine when I using button_click handler..

Comment: Which line is it referring to? And do you have a method called `PictureBoxSizeMode`?

Comment: @JonSkeet

On here `PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like your form has a *method* called `PictureBoxSizeMode`. You could either change the method name, or change the property setter to:

```
myPicBox.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
```

Changing the method name would be cleaner though.

Answer (score 0):

That error can only occur if you have a method named `PictureBoxSizeMode` in your code. You should rename that method to something else. A scenario like:

```
private void UserInput_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox myPicBox = new PictureBox();
    myPicBox.Location = new Point(7, 240);
    myPicBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(140, 140);
    myPicBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
    myPicBox.Margin = new Padding(3, 3, 3, 3);
    myPicBox.Visible = true;
}
private void PictureBoxSizeMode()
{
}
```

Or qualify it with the Namespace like.

```
myPicBox.SizeMode = myPicBox.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
```

Comment: ...or qualify the `PictureBoxSizeMode` enum with the entire namespace name (or an alias). Probably easier to remove the method though.